# Different logo each Wordpress page

Tags: php, html, wordpress

Found this code snippet to change header logo front page of wordpress by adding to header.php file.

```html
If (is_front() || is_home) {
//Your logo for the front page
}Else {
// Your other logo
}
```

How can I get something like this to call different logo for different Wordpress page ID's?

This is my themes call for the logo presently:

```html
<div class="logo"> 
    <?php $log_url = sh_set( $options, 'site_logo', get_template_directory_uri().'/images/logo.png' );
              $log_url = ( $log_url ) ? $log_url : get_template_directory_uri().'/images/logo.png';
     $logo_size = @getimagesize($log_url); //printr($logo_size); ?>
  <a title="<?php echo esc_attr(get_bloginfo('name')); ?>" href="<?php echo esc_url(home_url()); ?>">
   <img src="<?php echo esc_url($log_url); ?>" alt="<?php echo esc_attr(get_bloginfo('name')); ?>"  width="<?php echo sh_set( $logo_size, 0); ?>" height="<?php echo sh_set( $logo_size, 1); ?>" >
  </a> 
   </div>
```

And I should be able to add this call tag **is_page( array( 42, 54, 6 ) )** to it to add a different logo to just those pages, just don't know how.

Comment: You must know the id pages/posts and than create a switch case for eachone getting the id using get_the_ID() function from wp. reference here: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_id/. The get_the_ID() returns the id number of page or post. Hope it helps.

Comment: I know how to get the page/post ID's. Just I am not a coder and have tried myself and can't get call correct on my own

Answer (score 0):

**First Solution:**

Very simplest way to do different logo for different page in WordPress by using header.php

```
 <?php     
  $logo_default =  'get_template_directory_uri().'/images/logo_default.png'';         
  $logo_about = 'get_template_directory_uri().'/images/logo_about.png''; 
  $logo_team = 'get_template_directory_uri().'/images/logo_team.png''; 
        if (is_page('about-us')) {
            $logo_about;
        } elseif (is_page('team')) {
            $logo_team;
        }else{
              $logo_default;
        }
    ?>
```

**Another solution:**

```
  <?php
        $logo = 'default_logo'; 
        if (is_page('about-us')) {
            $logo = 'about_logo'; 
        } elseif (is_page('team')) {
            $logo = 'team_logo'; 
        } 
    ?>
```

Assuming you have about_logo.png logo for about-us page , team_logo.png for team page and default logo default_logo.png

```
<img src="/images/logo<?php echo $logo; ?>.png">
```

**FOR CSS YOU CAN TRY THIS**

```
.page-id-13072 .logo a {

   background: url(images/logopink.png) no-repeat; 
 }
```

Comment: Hi Muhammad, Thank you for solution. The CSS is almost working. Still showing the original logo red Team Ambrose: https://teamambrose.realtor/prestige-plus-home-inspections/. The blue stripes there is just a temporary picture that was added by your CSS trick. Just need to hide original logo now

Comment: Can i see the code joe ? Then i can definitely help you ?

Comment: Absolutely, just not sure exactly what you need, my whole header.php file? Not, just the logo section I included in original post?

Comment: if I could add the if "is_page( array( 42, 54, 6 ) )" then the url image I choose to the existing code I provided above. Think I would be good or maybe not that easy?

Comment: Have you try my explained methods